# Grunt: custom task development how-to

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, npm, gruntjs

I need to implement a custom Grunt task and I'm absolutely lost about the development workflow.

1. How do I develop a custom task and I simulate loading it using npm during development?
2. Is there any other way of distributing custom tasks instead of using `npm`? I mean, can I distribute a JavaScript file defining the whole custom Grunt task and import it in the `Gruntfile.js` directly?

Since the whole task would be in a very early development stage, maybe the effort of publishing it in `npm` isn't a good idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Grunt tasks are just node modules. Read up on that. You can use `npm link` to symlink modules into other ones.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

custom grunt tasks are basically node-modules which you can publish to the npm registry. take a look at existing ones, and the documentation how to build them here:

http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task

basically you just do something like this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // or use grunt.registerMultiTask
  grunt.registerTask('your-taskname', 'your task description', function () {
  });
};
```

to make it easy for you, you should use [grunt-init](http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding) with the [grunt-init-gruntplugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntplugin) which basically sets everything up for you!

if you dont want to publish your module to npm, you can install it in in your project from a git repository (for example using github):

```
$ npm install git+https://github.com/your-user/your-repository --save
```

the --save option saves it automatically as a dependency into projects package.json.

if you just want to include a single js file in your project with your task, put that in a directory of your choice (i use grunt-tasks here), and include it in your gruntfile like that:

```
grunt.loadTasks("./grunt-tasks");
```

that will try to include every js-file in that directory as grunt tasks.

Comment: (+1) Is `./grunt-tasks` relative to the `Gruntfile.js`?

Comment: yes! (... just 10 more characters ... that i can add the comment ;-))

Comment: hahaha, thanks for your effort, it seems the right path. I liked the fact I can import a task from a git repo. This is great!!

Comment: short and clean explanation - thanks, was looking for something like this! :)

quick question: I think there is an unnecessary ")" at the end of the example